# Flask: How to have multiple submit requests on one form/route path

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm making a blog in flask and I want to make it where I could submit the post as a draft or as a public post.  I gave it two buttons with the names "create_draft" and "create_post".

Each submit request is supposed to send the data to a different database table.

The problem is I could only submit the form when I hit the Create Draft button but I get a 400 error saying "Bad Request" when I hit the Submit Post button

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('create') }}" method="post" class="well">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create Blog Post</h2>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.title) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.url) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.category) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.body) }}

    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="create_draft" value="Create Draft">
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="create_post" value="Create Post">
</form>
```

What the conditional in the view is trying to say is if I click the button with the name 'create_draft' it submits the form data to the Draft table in the database and if I click the button with the name 'create_post' then it submits to the Post table.

```html
#create posts
@app.route('/dashboard/create', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def create():
 admin = True
 form = PostForm()
 the_id = current_user.get_id()
 the_name = current_user.name
 if form.validate_on_submit():
  if request.form['create_draft'] and request.method == "POST":
   draft = Draft(request.form['title'], request.form['url'], request.form['body'], request.form['category'], the_name)
   db.session.add(draft)
   db.session.commit()
   return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
  elif request.form['create_post'] and request.method == "POST":
   post = Post(request.form['title'], request.form['url'], request.form['body'], request.form['category'], the_name, the_id)
   db.session.add(post)
   db.session.commit()
   return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
 return render_template('posts/create.html', form=form, admin=admin)
```

Also when I switch the order of the conditionals it only submits the from first conditional listed but I get a 400 "Bad Request" error when I try to submit the request in the 'elif' statement.

Does anyone know how to make it possible to submit on a route with multiple request options without getting a 400 error?