# Flask - html form one button with multiple actions/routes

Tags: html, forms, flask

The closest I've found to what I'm trying to do is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005494/flask-how-to-have-multiple-submit-requests-on-one-form-route-path) but it mentions two or more buttons along with all the related answers. I have only one button but wish to be able to go to different flask routes based upon the form input. What I have so far is

```
<form action="/bass" method="POST"> <!-- IF/HOW CAN form action SUPPORT MULTIPLE ACTION/ROUTES -->
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                        <input name="input" class="input" type="text" placeholder="BASS">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                        <input name="input" class="input" type="text" placeholder="TENOR">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <p class="control">
                        <button class="button is-info searcher" type="submit">
                            Search
                        </button>
                </p>
            </div>
</form>
```

I get the input in flask like so

```
@app.route('/bass',methods=['GET','POST'])
def bass():
  if request.method == "POST":
    input = request.form['input']
```

But when I try the TENOR input it always goes to /bass since that's the only route defined. How can I go to /bass when input for the BASS placeholder & go to /tenor when input for the TENOR placeholder from a single button? Do I need a separate button for each form OR do I need JavaScript for this solution?

Comment: Why do you need multiple routes when you can have a single route that processes the input and calls different functions based on the information you pass in?

Comment: Thanks for reply @CodeLikeBeaker & initially I tried what you suggested. I created a route named choice. However when doing so the browser didn't go to the appropriate page. I could see the code for each route run (BASS, TENOR, etc..) but the browser remained on the choice page. Do you know if/how I can force the browser to the BASS, TENOR, etc. page?